# Change webview source from text field

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

In a basic webview app I want the user to be able to manually alter the link in a sort of preferences menu.

How would I connect the text field to the mWebView.loadUrl?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/your_link"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

---

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://domain.com/**your_link**/");
```

Also, I want the app to remember the link so that the user doesn't have to type it every time, just change it if needed.

Comment: You can send the String Url value as a parameter to the Activity that has the WebView, when users select on your menu.

Comment: you can use this library `https://github.com/lapism/SearchView`. it can save your search history. or you can do it manually using SharedPreferences

Comment: Can you please explain what you need

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS I simply want to allow the user to change the webview  link like in a settings/preferences tab.

Comment: For that you can do as suggested by @Html Tosin right.... Whats the problem in it.... sorry if i still can't understand what you need....

Answer (score 2):

You can save the address on `SharedPreferences`, retrieve it on load and load the `WebView`'s URL when you open the `Activity` or on some user action (press a `Button` for example):

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/change"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Change link"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**WebViewActivity.java**

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LINK_ADDRESS = "LINK_ADDRESS";
    private static final String BASE_ADDRESS = "http://www.google.es/search?q=";
    private static final String DEFAULT_ADDRESS = "";

    private WebView webView;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        editText.setText(settings.getString(LINK_ADDRESS, DEFAULT_ADDRESS));

        Button change = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change);
        change.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings
                        .edit();
                editor.putString(LINK_ADDRESS, editText.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();

                reloadWebView();
            }
        });

        reloadWebView();
    }

    private void reloadWebView() {
        webView.loadUrl(BASE_ADDRESS + editText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Sample code:

**DemoWebView.java**

```
public class DemoWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private AutoCompleteTextView edtUrl;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "HistoryPrefs";
public static final String PREFS_SEARCH_HISTORY = "SearchHistory";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Set<String> history;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    edtUrl = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_url);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser(DemoWebView.this));

    webView.canGoBack();
    webView.canGoForward();
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

    edtUrl.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://" + edtUrl.getText().toString());
                addSearchInput(edtUrl.getText().toString());
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    history = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(PREFS_SEARCH_HISTORY, new HashSet<String>());
    setAutoCompleteSource();
}

private void setAutoCompleteSource() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, history.toArray(new String[history.size()]));
    edtUrl.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addSearchInput(String input) {
    if (!history.contains(input)) {
        history.add(input);
        setAutoCompleteSource();
    }
}

private void savePrefs() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(PREFS_SEARCH_HISTORY, history);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    savePrefs();
}
```

}

**webview.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edt_url"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:hint="Enter URL Here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
        android:textColor="@color/black_alpha_80"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MyBrowser.java**

```
public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

private Activity mActivity;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private String mainUrl = "";

public MyBrowser(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
}

public MyBrowser(Activity activity, String mainUrl) {
    this.mainUrl = mainUrl;
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    showProgress();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    view.loadUrl("");
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, mActivity.getString(R.string.not_load_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}

@Override
public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
}

@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
        Log.e("Progress==>", view.getProgress() + "");
        dismissProgress();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        Log.e("Exception==", exception + "");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        showProgress();
    }
}

private void showProgress() {
    Util.isCancelable = true;
    mProgressDialog = Util.getProgressDialog(mActivity);
}

private void dismissProgress() {
    Util.isCancelable = false;
    Util.dismissDialog(mActivity, mProgressDialog);
}
}
```